# Subquery returns different number of rows than equivalent JOIN

Tags: mysql

I get different results when I use a subquery or a JOIN.

The query are these:

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    table2
WHERE
    table2.id NOT IN (
        SELECT fkfield FROM table1
    )
```

and

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    table2
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.fkfield = table2.id
WHERE
    table1.id IS NULL
```

(`table1.fkfield` has a FK constraint to `table2.id`)

First query returns 0 rows, second query returns 396 rows.

I've tried `OPTIMIZE TABLE` and export/import (with mysqldump) with no luck.
The engine is **Innodb**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: provide sample data showing the results of each query please

Comment: give the table structure to understanding

Comment: Please edit your question with a minimal sample data set for both tables which we may use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I guess that means there are some matches in your second query where the table1_id is null. Try checking by addng sum(case when table1_id is null then 1 else 0 end) to your select.

Comment: @P.Salmon You're right. It seems that was the problem, I added `WHERE fkfield IS NOT NULL` in the subquery and it works. I forgot the `NULL` crazy things in `IN` clause...
Create an answer so I can accept it, if you want :)

Comment: Thanks TimBiegeleisen, Bhupesh, Takarii. I was preparing table structure and data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that means there are some matches in your second query where the table1_id is null. Try checking by addng sum(case when table1_id is null then 1 else 0 end) to your select

Answer (score 0):

Left join is not exactly as you may expect

"The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all records from the left table (table1), and the matched records from the right table (table2). The result is NULL from the right side, if there is no match"
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

```
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.fkfield = table2.id
```

It return's the intersection and all of table2.id values

So

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    table2
WHERE
    table2.id NOT IN (
        SELECT fkfield FROM table1
    )
```

Returns only the intersection of table1 and table2

While

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    table2
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.fkfield = table2.id
WHERE
    table1.id IS NULL
```

Returns the intersection of table1 and table2 plus all values of table2.id